# Existe alguma forma de exeutar arquivos batch durante o build de um projeto Maven?

Tags: java, maven, batch

Eu tenho um arquivo .bat que executa alguns pre-requisitos durante o build do meu projeto Maven. Eu quero executar este arquivo .bat automaticamente quando eu fizer o build do projeto que eu desenvolvi

Existe alguma forma de realizar esta tarefa com o Maven?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Usando o [Exec Maven Plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/).

Com ele você pode executar outros [programas Java na mesma JVM](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/java-mojo.html) ou um [programa qualquer em um processo separado](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/exec-mojo.html).

Veja um [exemplo de uso](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/usage.html) para um arquivo `.bat`:

```xml
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            ...
            <goals>
              <goal>exec</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <executable>cmd.exe</executable>
          <!-- opcional -->
          <workingDirectory>c:\diretorio</workingDirectory>
          <arguments>
            <argument>/c</argument>
            <argument>build.bat</argument>
            <argument>parametro_bat</argument>
          </arguments>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
   ...
</project>
```

## Usando o [Maven Antrun Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/)

Se você já usa o Ant para algum outro projeto, esse plugin será ainda mais flexível.

Veja um exemplo extraído [desta resposta do SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12604890/1683070):

```xml
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.6</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
            <configuration>
                <target>
                    <exec executable="cmd.exe">
                        <arg value="/c"/>
                        <arg value="C:\pasta\arquivo.bat"/>
                    </exec>
                </target>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
       </execution>
   </executions>      
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar [esse](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/) plugin do maven, que permite você executar praticamente qualquer coisa durante as fases do maven. Como você quer executar antes do build (compile), a configuração ficaria assim:

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    ...
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
      <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.1</version>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <id>pre-bat</id>
          <phase>process-resources</phase>  // antes do compile
          <goals>
            <goal>exec</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
      <configuration>
        <executable>c:\pre_processamento.bat</executable> // caminho do seu bat
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
</build>
```

Para saber certinho quando você deve executar o plugin, ou seja, em qual fase, consulte a [referência](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference) do ciclo de vida do maven.

Answer (score 0):

O **Exec Maven Plugin** provê dois *goals* para executar programas de sistema e programas Java

```
exec:exec  que executa programa Java ou um programa arbitrário em um processo separado
exec:java  que executa programa Java na mesma JVM
```

Para invocar o goal use:

```
mvn exec:exec
```

Exemplo:

Para executar um programa escrito em Node JS (Teste.js) localizado no diretório /Users/joao_parana escreva o Segmento de POM.xml abaixo:

```
<build>
    <finalName>testeNode</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>exec</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <executable>node</executable>
                <!-- opcional -->
                <workingDirectory>/Users/joao_parana</workingDirectory>
                <arguments>
                    <argument>Teste.js</argument>
                </arguments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Você verá a saida do NodeJS na console se usar o codigo abaixo:

```
cat Teste.js 
console.log('Oi Mundo. Estou testando o Maven (goal exec:exec)')
```